# Python - Storing float values in CSV file

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I am trying to store the positive and negative score of statements in a text file. I want to store the score in a csv file. I have implemented the below given code:

```
import openpyxl
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
import csv
from senti_classifier import senti_classifier
from nltk.corpus import wordnet

file_content = open('amazon_kindle.txt')

for lines in file_content:
    sentence = sent_tokenize(lines)
    pos_score,neg_score = senti_classifier.polarity_scores(sentence)

    with open('target.csv','w') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f,lineterminator='\n',delimiter=',')
    
    for val in range(pos_score):
        writer.writerow(float(s) for s in val[0])
    f.close()
```

But the code displays me the following error in `for` loop.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\classifier.py",
> line 21, in  for val in pos_score: TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several errors with your code:

Your code and error do not correspond with each other.

```
for val in pos_score:  # traceback
for val in range(pos_score):  #code
```

`pos_score` is a float so both are errors `range()` takes an `int` and `for val` takes an `iterable`. Where do you expect to get your list of values from?
And from usage it looks like you are expecting a `list of list of values` because you are also using a `generator expression` in your `writerow`

```
writer.writerow(float(s) for s in val[0])
```

Perhaps you are only expecting a list of values so you can get rid of the `for` loop and just use:

```
writer.writerow(float(val) for val in <list_of_values>)
```

Using:

```
with open('target.csv','w') as f:
```

means you no longer need to call `f.close()` and `with` closes the file at the end of the `with` block. This also means the `writerow()` needs to be in the `with` block:

```
with open('target.csv','w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f,lineterminator='\n',delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(float(val) for val in <list_of_values>)
```